# How to pick multiple image from gallery Android

Tags: android, android-image, android-gallery

```
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;    
    private void fireGallerypick() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
    }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                System.out.println("Gallery pick success");
                String[] all_path = data.getStringArrayExtra("all_path"); //But it returns null
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

I can able to select multiple images and when i done selection. I need the path of all selected files in `String[]`. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK);
startActivityForResult(i, 200);
```

And to get the image-paths in onActivityResult, do like this -

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            String[] all_path = data.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");



        for (String string : all_path) {

            String sdcardPath = string;


        }
```

**Note: the EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE option is only available in Android API 18 and higher.**

Comment: I have already used it, how to get all the paths of selected images in `onActivityResult`...

Comment: `String[] imagesPath = data.getStringExtra("data").split("\\|");` returns null also i have tried `String imagesPath = data.getStringExtra("data");` this also returns null ..

Comment: Lemme have a look at it.

Comment: did you check it? @SaiKiran

Comment: Still it return null, `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65538, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/1944 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.abs_ind.www.example/com.abs_ind.www.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference`

Comment: check now, also edited startActivityForResult @SaiKiran